# Escape в Delphi есть решение?

Tags: delphi, escape

Дана строка:

```
\u041a\u0443\u043f\u0438\u0442\u0435 <b>\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435</b>
```

Как в Delphi привести ее в читаемый вид?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713491/delphi-decode-json-utf8-escaped-text

Comment: Почему у меня выходит ошибка на "LJSONValue: TJSONValue;" как неизвестный параметр TJSONValue, в "uses" добавил "DBXJSON"

Comment: какая версия делфей?

Comment: Delphi 10 Seattle

Comment: потому что мигрировало оно в `system.JSON`, но там и методы имзенились, так что этот вариант не прокатит видимо

Comment: вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713491/delphi-decode-json-utf8-escaped-text показана самописанная функция (всё свели к WideChar(c) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать вот так:

```
uses
  System.JSON,
  System.SysUtils;

function DecodeJsonUTF8(const AJsonUTF8: string): string;
var
  VJSONValue: TJSONValue;
begin
  VJSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue('"' + AJsonUTF8 + '"');
  try
    if VJSONValue <> nil then begin
      Result := VJSONValue.ToString;
    end else begin
      raise Exception.Create('JSON parse error!');
    end;
  finally
    VJSONValue.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure DoTest;
var
  VJSON: string;
  VText: string;
begin
  VJSON := '\u041a\u0443\u043f\u0438\u0442\u0435 <b>\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435</b>';
  VText := DecodeJsonUTF8(VJSON);
  Writeln(VText);
end;
```

Декодированная строка:

```
"Купите <b>женские</b>"
```

Comment: а что может быть с переданной строкой, чтобы вернулся `nil`? вообще,имхо,  лучше глянуть что там внутри происходит, ибо подключать целый юнит ради одной функции и делать ее по сути через костыль, как то не нормально.

Comment: @teran Она может быть невалидной с точки зрения json. А внутри там творится "Ад и Израиль", так что лучше пользоваться проверенной стандартной функцией (которую со временем могут оптимизировать/фиксить баги), а не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: А вообще, создаётся впечатление, что топикстартер явно делает что-то не так и парсит json руками, а не библиотекой. Иначе бы у него такого вопроса не возникло, ведь библиотеки всё парсят сами и возвращают строки в нормальном виде и строку в таком нечитаемом  виде просто неоткуда взять.

Comment: Ссылку ту что дал пользователь `teran` помогла частично понять, оно расшифровывает только если в строке нет лишних символов, код который дал пользователь `zed` справляется лучше чем те функции но всё равно есть ошибки.

Comment: Дело в том что мне приходит ответ от сервера и в строке 30к-50к символов, вот кусочек строки `\u0002@[ZUN\\r[\\A\\6V\u0017\fq\u0012 !@s\u0005h-BL(\\Dm\u0000\u000b\u0003a\reY^QAG` расшифровка функцией что дал `zed` останавливается когда доходит до `(\\Dm` да там вообще могут придти все возможные символы, мне нужно сделать escape как в javascript, а дальше функцией `XOR` идёт расшифровка этого бредо-текста. Я вот думаю может пробежаться по строке выбрать все \u**** декодировать и заменить их?  Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @lib Каков вопрос - таков ответ. Вы привели пример проблемной строки, я привёл код, её расшифровывающий. Если у вас проблемы с **другой** строкой, то создайте новый вопрос и приведите там в пример именно ту строку, с которой возникает проблема. А этот вопрос отметьте как решённый.

Comment: @lib И да, код из моего ответа расшифровывает приведенный вами в комментарии кусочек строки: `'#2'@[ZUN\r[\A\6V'#$17#$C'q'#$12' !@s'#5'h-BL(\Dm'#0#$B#3'a'#$D'eY^QAG` - он нигде не останавливается и обрабатывает её до конца.

Comment: @zed, у меня вот такой результат `"@[ZUN\r[\A\6Vq !@sh-BL(\Dm' останавливается на символе `\u0000` какое значение у него? И этот вариант всё равно не пойдёт, если в строке будут присутствовать двойные кавычки код остановится. А как раскодировать простую строку без спец. символов я узнал из поста пользователя @teran, про то что нужно подключить system.JSON тоже от него

Comment: @lib Вы просто не умеете правильно посмотреть результат декодирования, вот вам и кажется что у вас оно не работает.  А кавычки в строке и прочие спец символы также не помеха, т.к. они будут экранированы. Удивительно, как получив рабочий код, вы склонны думать, что он вам не подходит,  т.к. у вас супер уникальный случай. Это не так.